# Reserve a physical address space in linux

Tags: linux, memory-management

Is there any way to reserve a certain physical address space (say 0x2000 - 0x1000) in linux

i need to reserve it so linux doesn't use it in any way. it is used by some unrelated co-processor and so must be left unused.

Thanks

Comment: There is some way to disable a faulty range of physical RAM (to circumvent hardware issues) at boot time, but I forgot the details

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37729/how-can-i-reserve-a-block-of-memory-from-the-linux-kernel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to write a kernel module for that. See Chapter 15 "[Memory Mapping and DMA](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)" of "[Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)"

**[EDIT]** You can use the [Linux kernel parameter `memmap`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt)  for this:

```
memmap=4K$0x2000
```

Kudos go to  [Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch) (see comment above)

Comment: I already had a look there but couldnt find what i was looking for. i need to reserve a certain a space starting from a specific address. i am still not aware of ani API for that

Comment: thanks! i went through the documentation and this is exacly what i was looking for